# How do you store an API key (token) client side without the user being able to see/access it?

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, django, security

I am working on a project that is handling sensitive customer information. Obviously security is a high priority.
We have recently created an API that we want to use to be able to access the database to access / modify the data.
What is the best way to store an API token client side? We currently are using the meta tag of the html template file to store the csrf token, but we do not want the API token to be visible.

Here is the code for the csrf token and it works.

```
 //Capture and store the csrf Token
  useEffect(() => {
    const csrfToken = document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').getAttribute('content');
    setToken(csrfToken);
    console.log({sessionToken, csrfToken});
  }, []);
```

Here is the  tag for the index file we are using as a template

```
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token }}">
  <meta name="api-token" content="{{ request.session.api_token }}">
</head>
```

This also works, but then the API token is visible if someone inspects the page.

We are using a Django / Python backend and a React front end.
Would this involve the use of cookies? Or does it get more complicated than that?
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Let me know if you need to see any other parts of the code.

I tried adding it to the meta tag, and adding it to session storage. Neither of these options felt correct.

Comment: What you're trying to do is impossible.

Comment: How do you mean? How do people write secure APIs then?

Comment: Why is it important for security whether the user sees the API key? I mean, all they can do with it is what they already can do through the web interface, right?

Comment: Correct, but the API key doesn't change for each session. So if someone gained unauthorized access to the website and was able to extract the key, the would be able to access the data from anywhere.

Comment: Why does the key not change for each session? __Thats__ your vulnerability, not the visibility of the api key.

Comment: Let me clarify; the csrf token changes for each session. But if we wanted to allow 3rd party companies access the API, we would want them to be able to integrate using an API key that doesn't change. Otherwise they would need to send log in credentials with each API call.

Comment: Sounds like you need OAuth or something similar.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I will do some research on OAuth

Comment: The customer knows their API key. Why would you hide it from them?

Comment: @tkausl If there is no duplicate, you should probably post your comment as answer. I see similar questions from time to time without answer and it could help others to understand, that this is the wrong approach.

Comment: I assumed you would want to hide it so that if someone was able to gain unauthorized access, they wouldn't be able to just save the key and access the information..

Comment: you can set the token from server side with httponly and secure flag True. That will prevent any client side script to access the token.

Comment: Currently, if someone gets unauthorized access, they get the credentials. Is this also insecure? The question is unclear because it is unclear where the data comes from, who knows the data, and from whom you want to hide the data. If it's the customer's API key, there is no reason to hide it from them.

Comment: To say it simply if the API key is being used by the users browser / client anyone having direct access to it and who is determined enough to get the key can get it (Whether you use HTTP only cookies or anything else). There is no way to hide it from them. Also given that the API is probably for the website they get the token from you should probably simply use whatever authentication the website is already using and use the token only for programmatic access.

Comment: why couldn't you store API Key in server side ( in db, config file ...), if not going for oauth.

Answer (score 2):

Storing an API key client-side without exposing it to users can be challenging, as client-side code is inherently accessible to users. However, there are some techniques you can use to enhance security. Here are a few options:

**Server-side Proxy:** Instead of storing the API key directly on the client-side, you can create a server-side proxy that acts as an intermediary between your client and the API. The client sends requests to your server, which then includes the API key in the server-to-server communication with the actual API. This way, the API key remains hidden from the client. I found this on github about this method, maybe it is worth you taking a look at it: https://github.com/eofs/django-rest-framework-proxy

**Token-based Authentication:** Consider implementing token-based authentication, such as JSON Web Tokens (JWT), where the client exchanges a user-specific token for access to protected resources. The server can generate and manage these tokens, validating them on each request. This approach avoids exposing the API key directly to the client. More about JWT and implementing it with Django Rest Framework here: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-use-jwt-and-django-rest-framework-to-get-tokens/

**Backend Session Storage:** You mentioned using Django as the backend. One option is to store the API key securely in the backend session storage after authenticating the user. The session can be associated with the user's authenticated session, allowing the server to handle API requests on behalf of the user without exposing the API key to the client. See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/http/sessions/

**Server-Side Environment Variables:** This is a common practice; you can store the API key as an environment variable on the server-side. This way, the key remains hidden from the client code. Your backend code can then access the environment variable and use the key for API requests.

Remember, while these approaches enhance security, there is no foolproof way to completely hide sensitive information from a determined attacker who gains access to the client-side code. Therefore, it's crucial to implement additional security measures like server-side validation, rate limiting, and monitoring to protect sensitive customer information.

Comment: This answer looks like it was generated by an AI (like ChatGPT), not by an actual human being. You should be aware that [posting AI-generated output is officially **BANNED** on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If this answer was indeed generated by an AI, then I strongly suggest you delete it before you get yourself into even bigger trouble: **WE TAKE PLAGIARISM SERIOUSLY HERE.** Please read: [Why posting GPT and ChatGPT generated answers is not currently allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy).